# help me use proxy with twill

Tags: python

I read help here http://twill.idyll.org/browsing.html, then i open python and write

```
export http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
```

but i just receive an error. How can i use proxy with twill to browser web ?

Comment: and the error you get is... ?

Answer (score 2):

the export command is something you need to type on your shell (assuming unix/linux). It's not a python statement!

Comment: I receive this "Line 1 export http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128" ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax" Does any way for me to use it ?

Comment: what I said: It's a shell command, not a python command. Type it before you start python or your program

Comment: I understood what you say, but i don't know how to run it. I open cmd and type "export http_proxy='http://www.someproxy.com:3128' " but i receive error too.( 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command ). Where can I put this command ?